# Comparing two power series and extracting their coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, series-expansion, coefficients

I have a standard mathematical problem that I was wondering how to solve efficiently by mathematica. Here is the problem.

I have two power series expansions of a function `F[x,y] = sum1 = sum2`

```
A1 = (a/4)^2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2); 
A2 =  (a/4)^3 x y z;
sum1 = Sum[A1^i * A2^j * P[i, j], {i, 0, 6}, {j, 0, 6}] /. {z -> -x - y}
sum2 = Sum[(a/4)^(i + j) (x^i y^j)/(i! j!) Q[i, j], {i, 0, 6}, {j, 0, 6}]
```

Basically I want to express one type of coefficients `P[i,j]` in terms of `Q[i,j]`.

Comment: sum1 contains x-y terms with lowest total degree>0 of two, no terms linear in x or y. However sum2 contains terms linear in x or y. How can sum1 == sum2 be?

Comment: Doesn't that mean some of the particular coeffs i.e. `P[i,j]` or `Q[i,j]` are zero?

Comment: Maybe another way of putting it : sum1 is a restricted sum with `2 i + 3 j = n` where `n` is a natural number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sum2`, the powers of `x` and `y` are less than or equal to 6, whereas in `sum1`, the powers go up much higher.  For that reason, we'll have to truncate `sum1`.

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
Thread /@ Thread[CoefficientList[sum1, {x, y}][[;; 7, ;; 7]] == CoefficientList[sum2, {x, y}]] // Flatten;
Solve[%, Flatten@Array[Q, {7, 7}, 0]]
```

This generates the set of coefficients for each power of $x^ny^m$, sets them equal to each other for the two sums (up to degree 6 in each variable), and then solves for the `Q`'s in terms of the `P`'s.

Comment: That's perfect! I just wanted P[i, j] = # Q[i, j], but that's not so relevant. I think I understand the complication you mentioned, since I was struggling with the same. But I am yet to understand the resolution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On second thought, it's not so trivial to obtain `P[i, j] = # Q[i, j]`. Please let me know if you have any way to solve directly for `P[i, j]`. Thanks!